# Way to build LEGO spaceship with regular bricks

Tags: building

How do I  build a spaceship without buying a spaceship set?

With a limited amount of bricks, like, say 300 2x4, 100 2x2, and about 20 2x1 bricks.

I'm looking for instructions.

Comment: Could you be more specific with what you are looking for and what you've tried?

Comment: @Ambo100: Really, nothing... But I've been going through stuff in my head.

Comment: It depends on the scale and how "rough" you're willing the final product to be - here's a [Sailing ship built purely from 2x4s](https://twitter.com/Zhaph/status/539244369493393408)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.






Long answer: Yes. Your imagination is the limit. Wondering however what the intent of your question is .... are you looking for instructions on how to do this?

Comment: Yeah, sort of...

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what parts of building a spaceship are difficult to do?

Comment: Specifically, whats hard is the bottom.

Comment: If you overlap your bricks and make the base 1 stud smaller in all dimensions than the layer above it, you should get a really solid sloping bottom for a spaceship when using 2x4 bricks. It will look blocky, but given the appeal of Minecraft that should not be an issue nowadays :)